# How do I get my terrain to self-delete?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject, rigid-bodies

I set up this code in the deletion script, first off:

```
var terrain = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);

function Update ()
{
    if (terrain.position.x <= Camera.main.transform.position.x - 5)
    {
        Destroy(this.GameObject);
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the screen:

[image]

And my prefab stuff:

[image]

What I want is for, when the camera is in front of the prefab, I want it to delete itself. However, this is the error I get:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent (System.Type type)
Deletion..ctor () (at Assets/Scripts/Deletion.js:3)
UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(Object, Vector3, Quaternion)
Repeating Terrain:SpawnTerrain(Object) (at Assets/Scripts/Repeating Terrain.js:60)
Repeating Terrain:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/Repeating Terrain.js:52)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with a timer and use console/debug to make sure you have the right object

```
 Destroy (this.GameObject, 5);
```

or 
GameObject.Destroy(gameObject)

Comment: This didn't work. I did that, but it still wont delete. Remember, the error means that Unity doesn't even know what terrain is, which is weird because it is assigned with Get Component

Comment: Interesting. Try putting  terrain = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D); in the void Start{}   and make a var called public Rigidbody2D terrain ;

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out, I just needed to replace this.GameObject with this.gameObject. I capitalized it, that was all.

Comment: Good catch! Didn't see that, using capital usually means you are referring to the class.

Comment: I appreciate your help, so I'll give you the answer.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!